# How to force find not to stop searching for a directory

Tags: find

With

```
sudo find / -type d -name "*ext/standard/*"
```

I want to find the directories with *ext/standard* in it. But after

```
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

it stops searching.

How can it be **forced** to **not** stop searching?

Comment: `-name "*ext/standard/*"` will never match because file names never contain `/` characters. ITYM `-path` instead of `-name`

Comment: What OS and implementation of `find` is it? Is it really that exact command that caused that error message?

Answer (score 0):

Read `man find` and use the `-prune` argument to `find`.

```
find / -type d -name dev -prune ...
```

Comment: `-name dev` would prune all the directories called `dev`, not just `/dev`. If you wanted to skip the `/dev` directory, that would by `find / -path /dev -prune -o -type d -path '*ext/standard/*' -print`.